# Error "the project ' ' has been renamed or is no longer in the solution"?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm using visual studio 2010. I have the solution with many projects in it.

These projects were copied from other solution and I have renamed some projects.

The first time I built this solution successful, after that I closed solution and reopen it then when

I built it occurred error `"the project ' ' has been renamed or is no longer in the solution"`.

I have searched on this forum about my problem, read many ways but finally I must create new solution and add projects again => it can build successful at that time.

But unfortunately, this error happen again when I close and reopen solution.

Someone can show me the solution to remove this error absolutely?

Many thanks,

T&TGroup

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787851/the-project-file-has-been-renamed-or-is-no-longer-in-the-solution

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this same error message in VS2010.

I resolved it but opening the solution file (.SLN) and removing the line which referenced my projects. I was then able to re-add my projects to the solution and build it correctly.

```
ProjectReferences = "{F9859F0E-556D-44B5-BBDA-F4CEDEAA3226}|WebServiceInterface.dll;{ED5F7021-3E36-44D0-8362-577CFFF79090}|SharepointWeb.dll;"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been also face this problem.I caused this problem when I needed to rename my vcxproj and sln files, and the old project dependencies didn't match the new file names.

Here are some steps hopefully it will work for you......

removing all the projects from the solution, and adding them back in one by one to find the project file with the problem. Opening the file in notepad, I removed the project references at the bottom and saved the file. I reloaded the solution in VS 2010, and reset the project dependencies.

Comment: Thanks vikky, but as i mentioned above 
"I have searched on this forum about my problem, read many ways but finally I must create new solution and add projects again => it can build successful at that time.

But unfortunately, this error happen again when I close and reopen solution."

thanks anyway!